# Is there such a thing as an outlet with an indicator current is being drawn?

Tags: receptacle

I'm looking for an outlet for two plugs. Each plug should have an LED or something that turns on when current is drawn from that particular plug. Is there such a thing?

Searching the web for "outlet with LED indicators" and other combinations is giving results. However, it's usually a GFI with it's single indicator or outlets with "night light" type LEDs.

Updated:
I have two sump pumps (I get a lot of water) plugged into a duplex outlet. It's difficult to determine which one or both are running. Can't see in the murky water, vibrations of one pipe travel to the other. I'll usually unplug one, see if anything changes, then, unplug the other. If a pump is running, it's indicator should come on. Once stopped, the indicator should go off. And one indicator per pump. I don't have a problem making something.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want an outlet that has a LED/something that only lights up when power is being used, only when a light/something is on instead of just being plugged in but not on?  Have never seen something like that except for additional plug ins like 'watt meters' that read power consumed.   Or outlets with a power/live LED, but they only show outlet has power.

Comment: Please explain the context of your request more. What problem are you trying to solve? As it is it's just a shopping question, which is off topic.

Answer (score 3):

Not *exactly* what you are looking for, in terms of form factor, but it will have the desired net effect.

Get a multiple outlet strip with a master/slave configuration, [like this APC](https://amzn.to/3gYUpZ4):

[image: APC Surge Protector]

These are typically used for "Turn on computer, monitor and printer turn on automatically" or "Turn on TV, sound system turns on automatically", but can be used for just about anything.

Plug the device you want to monitor into the "Master" receptacle and plug a night light/table lamp/whatever into one of the "Controlled by master" receptacles.

Comment: @FreeMan It is overkill in the sense of "big cord & box instead of something tiny installed in the wall". On the other hand, it is $ 30, possibly a lot less (there are cheaper master/slave surge protectors, this is just the first one I found) and no real "installation" involved.

Comment: Maybe more "Rube Goldberg" than "overkill". ;) It does exactly what the OP asked for, but is somewhat more complex.

Comment: Rube Goldberg would be: Split the AC lines, put a CT on the hot, wire it up to a smart meter, connect that to a Raspberry Pi, programmed to read the smart meter and turn on/off an LED based on current reading.

Comment: Think OP is looking for something like a 'kill a watt meter', but without the meter, just a light when power is being used.

Comment: @crip659  I was also thinking a Kill a Watt device would be a good solution, there are several models. +

Comment: That is an excellent idea since it is flexible and allows to switch on any other (signaling) device like an acoustic warning etc.